# Using multiple cheap server to scale my website needs, which technology?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, openstack, beowulf

I have developed a website that is running on MySql/Php/Apache and it is performing quite well. But with more users uploading their stuff the space available on my server is reducing and eventually I will need some more computing power if the up trend stay.

What I will like to do is to be able to run an Ubuntu server and increase specs (disk space, CPU power) adding other cheap server. My host allow me to connect machine trough direct Gigabit Networks machines but suggestion on this matter are also welcomed. :=

I do not want use any expensive cloud server or managed stuff because budget is tight an I am fairly happy with my servers.

The main question is, which one is the technology/program that I can investigate and eventually use to achieve this goal? I have been reading a bit (Openstack, clustering, etc) & searching but more I read more I get confused.

The best would be something stable, fairly simple to set up and use even if performance & customization won't be top class...

It will be great to have some suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: IMO your question is overly broad and you are going to get multiple opinions. Personally I advise you look at LXC, OpenVZ, and/or KVM. Proxmox is a nice option - http://www.proxmox.com/

Comment: I wish to get some opinion :) You suggested virtualization products...am I missing something?